# How to map a database generated column in a SELECT in EF Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, orm, entity-framework-core

I'd like to use a temporary column that is generated by the MySQL database in a SELECT statement and read  it from the database with EF Core:

```
public async Task<List<Hydrant>> Search(double Latitude, double Longitude, float Radius)
    {
        var hydrants = await _context.Hydrants.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT *,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( {Latitude} ) ) * cos( radians( hydrant_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( hydrant_longitude ) - radians({Longitude}) ) + sin( radians({Latitude}) ) * sin( radians( hydrant_latitude ) ) ) ) AS hydrant_distance FROM ef_hydrants.hydrants HAVING hydrant_distance < {Radius}").ToListAsync();
        return hydrants;
    }
```

I need that column *hydrant_distance* only in this SELECT statement and the generated value depends on the parameters *Latitude*, *Longitude* and *Radius*.

That is also the reason that the following model property is not working for me:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[Column("hydrant_distance")]
public double Distance { get; private set; }
```

The column doesn't exist in the database because it's a generated column but when doing a simple SELECT statement the column would be read by EF Core like any other column:

```
public async Task<Hydrant> Get(uint id)
    {
        var hydrant = await _context.Hydrants.FindAsync(id);
        return hydrant;
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What you could try is creating a view which executes this query, create a second object having this property and map the view to this object.